# Adjust the width of an absolute positioned element, based on the content inside

Tags: css, css-position

I have a div(`container-right)` that is absolute positioned to the right;

Inside I have a toggle(show-hide) using a checkbox; Click on text - Tomandji.

The toggle shows a div(`content`), below the `container-right` and `container`.

I need the absolute positioned div(`content`), width to adjust based on the content inside; I need this because the content is dynamic.

In the example I have a list.

I want the `ul/li` to be horizontal and go below container(red) as necessary.

I don't want the `content` to get all the width of the `container`(red), but just adjust based on elements inside from right to left;

So, to have First Second Third inline.

```css
.toggle .trigger {
  cursor: pointer; }

.toggle input[type='checkbox'].trigger {
  display: none; }

.toggle .content {
  display: none; }

.toggle .trigger:checked ~ .content {
  display: block; }

.container { 
  height:120px;
  position: relative;
  background-color:red;
}

.container-right {
  background: #0069aa;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0; }
  
  .container-right .toggle {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
 }
    .container-right .toggle .trigger {
      color: #fff;}

      .container-right .toggle .trigger * {
        display: block; }
        
      .container-right .toggle .trigger::after {
        content: "a";
    }
      .container-right .toggle .trigger:checked ~ label {
        color: #4FA738; }
        
      .container-right .toggle .trigger:checked::after {
        content: "x"; }
        
    .container-right .toggle .content {
      background: #0069aa;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      display:none;
      top: 71.5px; }
      
      .container-right .toggle .content ul li {
        display: inline-block; }
        
        ul {
        padding:0
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="container-right">
        <div class="toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle"  class="trigger"/>
            <label for="menu-toggle" class="trigger">
                <span>Tomandji</span>
            </label>
    <div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li class="c-list__item"><a href="#">First link</a></li>
        <li class="c-list__item"><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
        <li class="c-list__item"><a href="#">Third link</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what will be content in `li` and will it be too long?

Comment: Remove the default padding of the `ul`, that seems to fix it already in this instance.

Comment: @AravindS ; just links

Comment: @CBroe - I remove it, doesn't change the issue, but why do you think ul padding, is connected with the width, and the fact the li are not horizontal ?

Comment: With absolute positioning, the calculation method for an unspecified width becomes “shrink-to-fit”. The browser _makes_ you LI “narrower” to try and find a solution that works. Removing the UL padding seems to kinda indirectly fix it in this instance, at least in Chrome; if that is not enough, then you need to do something else to make your list item content “demand” a certain width - either by specifying one or a min-width, or by suppressing automatic line breaks using `white-space`, or something like that.

Comment: @CBroe I test In Chrome/Firefox white-space and padding: 0 but doesn't work; width works but I don't know the width before content is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @CBroe you can add `white-space:nowrap` to `.content`. Below is a working example.

```css
.toggle .trigger {
  cursor: pointer; }

.toggle input[type='checkbox'].trigger {
  display: none; }

.toggle .content {
  display: none; }

.toggle .trigger:checked ~ .content {
  display: block; }

.container { 
  height:120px;
  position: relative;
  background-color:red;
}

.container-right {
  background: #0069aa;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0; }
  
  .container-right .toggle {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
 }
    .container-right .toggle .trigger {
      color: #fff;}

      .container-right .toggle .trigger * {
        display: block; }
        
      .container-right .toggle .trigger::after {
        content: "a";
    }
      .container-right .toggle .trigger:checked ~ label {
        color: #4FA738; }
        
      .container-right .toggle .trigger:checked::after {
        content: "x"; }
        
    .container-right .toggle .content {
      background: #0069aa;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      display:none;
      top: 71.5px;
      /* ###### Add this ###### */
      white-space: nowrap;
      }
      
      .container-right .toggle .content ul li {
        display: inline-block; }
        
        ul {
        padding:0
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="container-right">
        <div class="toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle"  class="trigger"/>
            <label for="menu-toggle" class="trigger">
                <span>Tomandji</span>
            </label>
    <div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li class="c-list__item"><a href="#">First link</a></li>
        <li class="c-list__item"><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
        <li class="c-list__item"><a href="#">Third link</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```